# read and remember file line by line in python

Tags: python, regex

I have some data list that I have to read line by line and then parse with regexp that extracts useful data from me:

now the code looks like:

```
counter = 0 # first line of the file

with open(data) as f:
    for line in f:
        counter += 1
        f.readlines()[counter]
        ...
        name = re.search(r'(?<=-)\d.*?(?=\s)', line)
        ...
```

So now `line` has the first line of the text file and I can apply some regexp on it to extract the data, the main problem is that it does not seem to work as expected, I know that the solution is not elegant, but what I need is:

- Have a single line remembered in a variable untill next iteration
- Check if there is the end of the file and then exit
- all file's lines can't be parsed at once
- Posible size of text file is not known

I feel bad about my solution because it is not pytonish at all and there are possible further problems in case I will have to handle large amount of data. I really searched a lot and have found nothing useful for my case.

Comment: `f.readlines()` reads the whole file at once, leaving no data for `for line in f`. Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `for line in f` you are iterating through the file line by line, so you don't need anything other than that in your case. For example:

```
with open(data) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip() # <- use this if you want to get rid of new line character
        name = re.search(r'(?<=-)\d.*?(?=\s)', line)
        # your code
```

This will also stop the loop and close the file when it reaches end of file so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Does not it parse the whole file at once? The reason for that code logic is that extracted data wil be used for changing the directory and also in the git commit message, so commit data is depending on the file entry and should be different (for example if I have 60 file enteries I will have to make 60 different commits:))

Comment: It will be parsed line by line, like it will jump to next line after the whole code is executed.

Comment: Using `for line in f.read().splitlines():` will eliminate the need to use `line = line.rstrip()`.

Comment: @ZachGates this will lead to an extra loop through the file which can be an issue if the file is big